# Set an entire field row value if equal to a single value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Sorry for the confusing title, but I couldn't find a better way to explain it.

I have some results where one row should populate an entire row if a specific code is found.

Here's the data:

```
PartID   CustomerID  Status    Qty   Notes
1000     900123      1         10    NULL
911      900123      1         5     NULL
```

Here's what I want it to do:

```
PartID   CustomerID  Status    Qty   Notes
1000     900123      1         10    911
911      900123      1         5     911
```

How could I write a query to give the notes field a value of 911 if one PartID has a value of 911?

EDIT: Thanks for the replies everyone, but I was hoping I could use a Select statement to accomplish this. I accomplished this by using a temp table, updating if the customer has a 911 in their order, updated only that customer's notes with 911, then queried the temp table for the data.

Comment: Not going to update with a Select statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE Table 
SET Notes=(CASE WHEN (SELECT Count(1) FROM Table Where PartId=911)>0 THEN 911 ELSE NULL END)
```

or

```
UPDATE t
SET t.Notes= t2.PartId
FROM Table t
LEFT JOIN Table t2 on t2.PartId=911
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update #t
set Notes=(select PartID from #t where PartID in(911))

select * from #t
```

[SEE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/17545)

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like

```
update MyTable
set Notes = '911'
where (select count(1) from @MyTableVar where PartID = 911) > 0
```

For example:

```
DECLARE @MyTableVar table( PartID int,
                           CustomerID int,
                           Status int,
                           Qty int,
                           Notes varchar(50));

insert into @MyTableVar(PartID, CustomerID, Status, Qty, Notes)
values (1000, 900123, 1, 10, null)

insert into @MyTableVar(PartID, CustomerID, Status, Qty, Notes)
values (911, 900123, 1, 5, null)

select * from @MyTableVar

update @MyTableVar 
set Notes = '911'
where (select count(1) from @MyTableVar where PartID = 911) > 0

select * from @MyTableVar
```

EDIT: 
To just change the returned values, rather than updating the database you could do the following (based on the above example):

```
select 
  mtv.PartID, 
  mtv.CustomerID, 
  mtv.Status, 
  mtv.Qty, 
  case when (select count(1) from @MyTableVar where PartID = 911) > 0 
    then '911' 
    else mtv.Notes 
  end as Notes 
from 
  @MyTableVar mtv
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select PartID, CustomerID, Status, Qty, 
case when exists(select * from notes where PartID = 911) then '911' else Notes end Notes
from notes
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to split the logic in two separate moves:

```
--1. check condition
declare @IsPartIDDetected int = 0;
if exists (select PartID from Notes where PartID = 911 )
  set @IsPartIDDetected = 1;

--2. get filteredoutput
select PartID, CustomerID, Status, Qty,
  case when @IsPartIDDetected = 1 then '911' else COALESCE(Notes,'') end as Notes
from Orders
```

This solution has an optimal execution plan and will cost less RAM.
COALESCE command added as an example of NULL values processed.

You can also wrap it into single CTE statement:

```
WITH partCondition as ( 
    select top 1 PartID as conditon from Notes where PartID = 911
)
    select PartID, CustomerID, Status, Qty, 
      case 
        when exists ( select * from partCondition ) 
          then 911        --conditon met
          else Notes end  --condition NOT met
        as Notes
    from Orders;
```

This will help to lower execution costs.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what one partID means
Do you mean CustomerID with one partID of 911?

run these two statements:

```
update customer 
   set notes  = 911
 where partID = 911 
   and notes <> 911;

update c2 
   set c2.notes = 911
  from customer c1 
  join customer c2 
    on c2.CustomerID = c1.CustomerID
   and c1.partID = 911 
   and c2.partID <> 911
   and (c2.notes <> 911 or c2.notes is null);
```

this one statement might do it but not sure it would be faster:

```
update c2 
   set c2.notes = 911
  from customer c1 
  join customer c2 
    on c2.CustomerID = c1.CustomerID
   and c1.partID = 911 
   and (c2.notes <> 911 or c2.notes is null);
```